# Is there any simple way to prove |Q| = |N0|

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**How can I prove |Q| = |N0|** 
where Q is the set of positive rational numbers
and N0 is the set of positive natural numbers with zero

Comment: This statement is false.

Comment: Do you mean Q is positive rational numbers?

Comment: can you briefly explain why?

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ typically represents the set of rational numbers, and in that case, indeed $|\mathbb Q| = |\mathbb N_0|$

Comment: You can prove that $|\Bbb Q|=|\Bbb N|$ where $\Bbb Q$ is the set of **rational** numbers (*or the positive rational numbers if you insist*).  The **irrational numbers** on the other hand are uncountable.

Comment: So if Q is a set of rational number then how can this statement be proved?

Comment: You can follow the link above, which will transport you to a the same question with seven anwsers, Dhanush.

Comment: Please google "proving the rationals are countable".  This is a very very well known, much talked about and easy to research question.  It's practically impossible for me to imagine you making any effort and not finding a solution somewhere.